# Trigger a Firestore Query when application variable changes

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

This is probably a very basic question, but I am new to SwiftUI and Firestore, so I am struggling a bit. I am building an app that shows the location of clubs near me. I have my Clubs collection in Firestore and each document has a geoPoint and geoHash. When I start up the app, I am using the location manager to provide me the current location, which I then convert into a searchGeoHash and searchGeoBox, and then query Firestore as follows:

```
@Published var searchGeoHash: String = Geohash.encode(latitude: locationManager.location?.latitude ?? 0, longitude: locationManager.location?.longitude ?? 0, 5)
@Published var searchGeoBox: [String] = (Geohash.neighbors(String(searchGeoHash.prefix(4)))?.sorted())!

self.db.collection(K.Firebase.clubCollection)
    .whereField("clubActive", isEqualTo: true)
    .whereField("clubGeoHash", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: searchGeoBox[0])
    .whereField("clubGeoHash", isLessThanOrEqualTo: searchGeoBox[7])
    .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            print("Error fetching Club documents: \(error!)")
            return
        }
        self.clubList.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        print("Club Count - from Firestore: ", documents.count)

        for doc in documents {
            let mappedDoc = Club(dictionary: doc.data())
            self.clubList.append(mappedDoc!)
        }
        self.clubListCount = self.clubList.count
        print("Club Count - from Field: ", self.clubList.count)
    }
```

This works as it shows me the clubs within the range.

I have another function that allows the user to change their location to search for clubs in another location. For example, I am currently in Boston but I want to search for clubs in New York. This function updates the searchGeoHash and searchGeoBox

This issue is how do I trigger this query automatically to update since I have changed the searchGeoHash and searchGeoBox.

Do I have to re-run the query or do I use setup searchGeoHash and searchGeoBox in a different way? Should I use Observed objects or Combine?

Comment: I assume you only want a single snapshot listener performing a single geoquery at a time, right? In other words, when the user changes location, that location should take the place of the current location, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I trigger this query automatically to update since I have
> changed the searchGeoHash and searchGeoBox.

You can use `didSet`:

```
@Published var searchGeoHash: String = Geohash.encode(...) {
    didSet {
        // trigger your query...
    }
}
```